# Restore Error event id 17066 and 3624 while restoring diff backup

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, filestream

I am getting the following error while restoring the Diff back up after restoring the Full backup in Norecovery mode.

I am unable use `dbcc checkdb` as the database in restoring db.Issues happens only in three instance where there is totally 6 instance. In other instance restore is working fine.

Error:

> Msg 5052, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> ALTER DATABASE is not permitted while a database is in the Restoring
>   state.
>
> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
>
> Location:     filesystem.cpp:526
>
> Expression:   newTree.IsInArchive ()
>
> SPID:         98
>
> Process ID:   1956
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
>
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>
> Msg 3624, Level 20, State 1, Line 22
>
> A system assertion check has failed. Check the SQL Server error log
>   for details.
>
> Typically, an assertion failure is caused by a software bug or data
>   corruption. To check for database corruption, consider running DBCC
>   CHECKDB. If you agreed to send dumps to Microsoft during setup, a mini
>   dump will be sent to Microsoft. An update might be available from
>   Microsoft in the latest Service Pack or in a QFE from Technical
>   Support.

Help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: What T-SQL did you run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A system assertion check has failed. Check the SQL Server error log for details. Typically, an assertion failure is caused by a software bug or data corruption. To check for database corruption, consider running DBCC CHECKDB

[This error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280499.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can be caused by transient, timing-related errors, or by in-memory or on-disk data corruption.

This message also says that the backup set which you are trying to restore as differential backup is actually not consistent and SQL Server cannot bring database to a logical point if you try to apply this backup. The assertion checks are either SQL Server bugs or something corrupt in database.

You can bring database online and can run regular `dbcc checkdb` command and post the output

You need to also check your differential backup is consistent and you can do that by below command

```
restore verifyonly from disk='backup_location\backup.bak'
```

run above command and paste the result in question

> I am unable use dbcc checkdb as the database in restoring db.Issues happens only in three instance where there is totally 6 instance. In other instance restore is working fine.

Since database is in recovery mode you cannot run any command on it that is why every command you run on it fails

Lastly can you also add output of

```
sp_readerrorlog
```

Comment: Assertion failures are mostly bugs in SQL Server. An assert is a runtime verification of a condition the programmer did not think was possible under any circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply restore the Database without any database file.

Try this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [yourDatabase] WITH RECOVERY
```

It won't hurt your database. It will just remove the `IN RESTORING`-State and you can then run your `DBCC CHECKDB` and whatever you want.

Comment: If you read OP's question he is asking that he is getting error while restoring diff backup, your command will bring database online so how diff backup would be restored. This is incorrect answer